# Facebook like Notifications in Rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications

I am using Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.3. I am implementing Facebook like Notifications in my Rails application. Not sure how to update the counter & the messages in the pop-up without refreshing the page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Rails case. You should use jQuery or better: ReactJS :P.